# How to run multiple queries based on filters

Tags: apex, soql

I need to display related opportunities with matches same gsm and asset tracker and other conditions need to display in lead level.

For example:

1. query on asset tracker & gsm  matches
2. If first list is empty i need to search only gsm matches
3. If second list empty look for other filter.

My like looks like

```
newopplist=[Select Id,StageName,Type from Opportunity where Asset=:assetset 
            AND Oppgsm=:gsmset AND StageName='Closed Won' ];
    if(newopplist.size() < 1)
    {
    newopplist=[Select Id,StageName,Type from Opportunity where 
                 Asset=:assetset AND StageName='Closed Won' ];
    }
```

But two conditions are working fine if i try to filter like same way i am unable to get results.

Please let me know is it the better way to find

Comment: Please stop introducing every post with "Hi friends I have a requirement like".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to first run a SOQL which could give you all values including or excluding `Oppgsm`

Then from the List, you will create separate list based on conditions.

Since you are firing SOQL queries multiple times on `Opportunity`, so better fire the SOQL once, get the list and filter in the for loop.

```
Map<String,String> gsmset = new Map<String,String>();
gsmset.put(key,value);

newopplist=[Select Id,StageName,Type, Oppgsm 
            From Opportunity 
            WHERE Asset=:assetset 
            AND StageName='Closed Won' ];



for(Opportunity oppty:newopplist)
{
    if(gsmset.containsKey(oppty.Oppgsm))
    {
        //prepare your desired list
    }
    else{
        //prepare your desired other list
}
```

**Update based on comments**

If you want to match gsmset with startswith, here is the approach:

```
for(Opportunity oppty:newopplist)
{
    for(String str:gsmset.values())
    {
        if(str.startsWithIgnoreCase(oppty.Oppgsm))
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: N.B. the "if" statement is not actually required here

Comment: I thought that he will try to match the dataset based on `Oppgsm` and create a new list

Comment: sorry - i meant the first 'if' statement

Comment: oh, thats my habit, I will remove

Comment: I tried to customize my code with your suggestion.But i want to match gsmset with startswith not contains any possibility is there.@SantanuBoral

Comment: That can be done. see my updated answer